# Convert class to Python list

Tags: python

I can't convert a simple `[0, 20, 0, 20, 0, 20]` to a `list`.

**Code:**

```
geo = hou.pwd().geometry()

print geo.boundingBox()
print type(geo.boundingBox())
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 20, 0, 20, 0, 20]
<class 'hou.BoundingBox'>
```

Test:

```
list(geo.boundingBox())
len(geo.boundingBox())
```

I get the following error:

```
object BoundingBox is not iterable.
Object of type 'BoundingBox' has no len()
```

I read all the related questions but they don't seem to solve my problem.

Comment: classes may override the __str__() and __repr__() methods to display anything they want. Just because they display to look like a list doesn't mean they are.

Comment: What are the attributes of `hou.BoundingBox`? Are you able to get it's size by calling `len(geo.boundingBox())` (or similar)? Are you able to index into it (`geo.boundingBox()[1]`)?

Comment: @GregS yes, I know what you mean, I tried from string to list but I get the classic : ['[', '0', ',', ' ', '2', '0', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '2', '0', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '2', '0', ']']

Comment: Where are these objects from?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, I added your question

Comment: It appears to be one of [these](http://www.sidefx.com/docs/houdini13.0/hom/hou/BoundingBox). I would recommend using the `maxvec` and `minvec` methods.

Comment: @user2357112, maxvec and minvec returns the same type

Comment: @Neo: If you mean they return `BoundingBox`es, no they don't. If you mean they return the same type as each other, I don't see why that matters.

Comment: @user2357112 It returns <class 'hou.Vector3'>, it's a class

Comment: Yes, but those are easily convertible to lists, as they support `__len__` and `__getitem__`. Ignacio's answer shows you how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Vector3`s can be converted to `list` since they implement item access methods.

```
list(geo.boundingBox().minvec()) + list(geo.boundingBox().maxvec())
```

Comment: This does not work you have to call boundingbox first

Comment: geo.boundingBox().maxvec()

Comment: by saying Item access methods, you mean iterable?